# Create new column in mySQL using values from other columns

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two columns in my database I'd like to combine to make a new third column. The first column is a company name and the second is the URL to the company website.

I'd like to make a new column that is the company name hyperlinked to the website:

```
<a href="http://companywebsite.com>Company Name</a>
```

Is there a simple way to go about doing this? I'm VERY new to mySQL and can't figure out how I'd even go about doing this.

Bonus points for coming up with a way where when I add a new entry with company name and URL it automatically generates a value for this new hyperlink column.

Thanks.

Comment: I would not add this column at all; it contains no new data and duplicates existing data - can't you build the URL as and when needed or in your client layer?

Comment: Please post a schema and some sample data - it should be easy to construct the data you want from the columns that are already there, rather than storing it explicitly.

Comment: Would suggest the same as Alex K. If you need it on database level you could use a view.

Comment: @ Alex Unfortunately, I'm using a plugin to render the tables in a WP page and it doesn't allow for any real customization. I can just make a simple query and that's it, so it seems like having everything in the table is the only option.

Comment: @Neville Dumped a few lines into an SQL file: http://cl.ly/code/320B2t2S2c3G

Comment: I would go with a View as suggested by mreiterer with Polvonjon's SELECT

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Polvonjon write, use CONCAT:

```
SELECT brief_description, CONCAT('<a href="', link, '">', innovation_name, '</a>') FROM inno_db
```

By the way - `inno_db` is a very odd name for a table in the database; it's a particular type of storage engine for MySQL. Do you not think "companies" is a better name?

Creating a new column is a bad idea - you have to keep it updated, and you're duplicating data, which leads to bugs in the long term. Ideally, you use the query to populate your WP screen.

If you can't do that, as the comments recommend, you could create a view, from which you can just do a straight select:

```
create view WPPlugin
as

select brief_description, 
CONCAT('<a href="', link, '">', innovation_name, '</a>') 
FROM inno_db
```

in your plug in code, you then do `select * from WPPlugin`.

Comment: This generates a SQL query result (I guess), but I need it to add this data to an existing column (hyperlinked_name). How do I do that? Tried adding UPDATE 'hyperlinked_name' but that didn't work.

Comment: I'm following your update and this is close, but I need one other column (description) to be included in this view that I use for the plugin. So it should be this newly created column and description (an existing column in the table). Can I create a view with both of these?

Comment: Wait...I see that it's pulling all the columns, so this is perfect...One problem...the new column has entries like this: <�a href="http://www.gweepi.com/">Gweepi Medical<�/a> How do I get rid of the � ?

Comment: I've updated the answer. I can see you're new here, but if you include all these details in your question, you'll get better answers.

Comment: Where do you see those characters - when you execute the query in  SQL window, or on the web page? If the latter, read this: http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/esc_url

Comment: They're fine in the SQL window, but not on the webpage. I checked out the link, but can't quite figure our where I'd need to make my updates in my theme to make this happen.

Answer (score 0):

Try use CONCAT function:

```
SELECT company, url, CONCAT('<a href="', url, '">', company, '</a>') FROM companies
```

But I will not advice to using this sample of getting anchor tag.
Try to use VIEW element in your MVC app.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have a table with three columns 
    CREATE TABLE mytable (
      company_name text
    , url          text
    , hyperlink    text
    )

Then you would need to UPDATE the value of the third column (hyperlink) based on what you need, something like:

```
UPDATE mytable
SET    hyperlink = '<a href="http://' || url || '>' || company_name || '</a>';
```

Comment: This just resulted in 0 being added to the new column